# String Handling problems in C

Tags: c

I  just made a code that finds the last digit and the last alphabet in the string which is as follows:-

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char str[100] = "a1b2c3d4", ldig=-1, lalpha=-1, i;
    
    for(i=0; i < sizeof(str)-1; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] >= 48 && str[i] <= 57)
            ldig = i;
            
        else if(str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)
            lalpha = i;
            
        else if(str[i] >= 65 && str[i] <= 90)
            lalpha = i;
    }
    
    if(ldig != -1)
        printf("%c ", str[ldig]);
        
    if(lalpha != -1)
        printf("%c", str[lalpha]);  
}
```

This gives me the correct output i.e

```
4 d
```

But when I try to use scanf or gets to input the data instead of predefining the string, I get the incorrect output.

**Please Help**

Comment: "But when I try to use scanf or gets". Show that code. Can't tell you what may be wrong with it if we can't see it. Guess: incorrect use of `sizeof` instead of `strlen`.

Comment: There is no guarantee `char` is signed on any implementation. Suggestion: `char str[100] = "a1b2c3d4"; signed char ldig = -1, lalpha = -1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(str)` is not the same as `strlen(str)`. You should use the latter. `sizeof` yields the size of the type, not necessarily the length of the string.

Also, avoid subracting from an `unsigned` value. Prefer `i + 1 < strlen(str)` to `i < strlen(str) - 1`, in case the length is zero. **Although in this case, you need `i < strlen(str)` anyway**. Change the type of `i` to a `size_t` while you're at it.

Then use the standard library functions `isdigit`, `isupper`, `islower`, &c. rather than hardcoding the encoded values - which are not portable.

Comment: strlen() worked fine... Thanks